# Save history data

Tags: grails

I want to save what the current user has added or edited from the app but I was wondering how to do it,i am connected to local postgresql database.Is there a way to create function and tell that function what to save in an sql table if a particular controller is executed?

Comment: Check out https://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but **grails filters** may be what you need.

check out :

[grails.org](http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html)

[Grails user guide](http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/guide/single.html#filters)